# question on tensorflow serving's performance improvement

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-serving

We have a tfs cluster for model serving. Each model server loaded about 2 dozens of model.

And we noticed an interest thing. While with the qps of model serving request increasing from 150 to 200, the average inference duration on each model server drops by 0.5ms.

I am confused by this result, since model server not configured 'enable-batching'. Why would the performance is getting better.

I'm looking forward to someone could answer it, thanks~

Comment: I'm not pretty sure. It maybe caused by [SavedModel Warmup](https://www.tensorflow.org/tfx/serving/saved_model_warmup).

Comment: Are you asking, "Why does TensorFlow Serving seem to process queries more quickly when serving more requests?"